# HelloWorld.deployed().balance.call() is not working

Tags: truffle

I entered the command correctly but I am still getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined at evalmachine.:1:19 
at ContextifyScript.Script.runInContext (vm.js:35:29) 
at Object.exports.runInContext (vm.js:67:17) at TruffleInterpreter.interpret (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/lib/repl.js:99:17) 
at bound (domain.js:280:14) at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12) 
at REPLServer. (repl.js:545:10) at emitOne (events.js:96:13) 
at REPLServer.emit (events.js:188:7) at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:239:10)
```

I would really appreciate some help on the matter.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the code? (Or a link to it.)

Answer (score 1):

Truffle uses [Promises](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_promises.html) to handle asynchrony, that is why `deployed()` returns promise, not a contract instance.

So you need `.then()` to get instance:

```
HelloWorld.deployed().then(hello => console.log(hello.balance.call()))
```

Or you can expose contract instance as a global variable:

```
let hello;
HelloWorld.deployed().then(res => hello = res);
hello.balance.call();
```

If you see `HelloWorld has not been deployed` error message then try to run `truffle migrate` or `truffle migrate --reset` before jumping to console.

Relevant Truffle [doc page](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/contracts#making-a-transaction).