# HelloWorld contract using truffle v3.2.1

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-invocation

I made my first very simple HelloWorld smart contract :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract HelloWorld {
    uint public balance;

    function sayHi() returns (bool success) {
        balance = 1000;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Trying to deploy all using truffle in a testrpc local network 
My deploy contracts looks like this :

```
var HelloWorld = artifacts.require("./HelloWorld.sol");
module.exports = function(deployer) {

  deployer.deploy(HelloWorld);
};
```

I `truffle build && truffle migrate` and then try to use my contract, I can see that my contract is correctly deployed, I can access my testrpc network (accounts available etc ...)  but I try to get my balance :

```
truffle(development)> var aHelloWorld = HelloWorld.deployed()
undefined
truffle(development)> aHelloWorld.balance.call().then(console.log)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

It doesn't find my balance property ... however if I `console.log` my `aHelloWorld` object, I can see that it has a balance property.

and then I called :

```
truffle(development)> aHelloWorld.toString()
'[object Promise]'
```

So it seems that my contract stays as a promise, I tried  :

```
truffle(development)> aHelloWorld.then(function (myContract) { 
  myContract.sayHi().then(); 
  console.log(myContract.balance.call().then(console.log))
})
Promise { <pending> }
undefined
truffle(development)> { [String: '1000'] s: 1, e: 3, c: [ 1000 ] }
```

It correctly changed my balance, I am happy but reaally confused... I've watched few tutorials and also read some answers here about basic steps like [Truffle error: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15078/truffle-error-cannot-read-property-call-of-undefined)
It works for them all by doing `HelloWorld.deployed().balance.call()...`

I mean accessing the contract directly through `HelloWorld.deployed()` without waiting for the promise ...
Is it because the version of truffle I use or am I doing something wrong ?

UPDATE : 
Even truffle tutorial shows direct access to the `deployed()` object : 
http://truffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/testing/

Answer (score 2):

Can't believe I found answer on a youtube video comment :

> Truffle change to call this way
>
> `HelloWorld.deployed().then(a => console.log(a.address))`

link to the youtube video : [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jI1TuEaTro&t=1850s)

Which mean in my case `HelloWorld.deployed().then(a => console.log(a.balance))`, or `HelloWorld.deployed().then(a => console.log(a.balance.then(console.log)))`, to get answer directly
So yes truffle changed their way of accessing contract in newer versions, they should update their doc

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11935/problem-with-truffle-console-cannot-read-property-call-of-undefined/13541#13541

Comment: Thanks @BadrBellaj, that question didn't appear with the similar questions

Answer (score 1):

In order to make life a little bit easier you can also do it like this:

First you can assign the contract to variable:

```
truffle(development)> HelloWorld.deployed().then(function(instance){helloWorld=instance})
```

Since balance is a public variable the compiler will create a getter function for you. To get the balance you can call:

```
truffle(development)> helloWorld.balance.call()
```

or to assign the balance to a variable you can call:

```
truffle(development)> var balance = helloWorld.balance.call()
```

To call the function sayHi you would call:

```
truffle(development)> helloWorld.balance.sayHi()
```